# How do I load tables in AWS RDS MySQL and Aurora MySQL databases using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in MySQL Workbench 8.0 without getting Error Code 1148?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been successfully loading data into tables in an Amazon Web Services (AWS) RDS MySQL 5.7 database from my laptop using a set of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE commands for several months, using an earlier version of MySQL Workbench. When I recently upgraded to MySQL Workbench 8.0 (without changing the underlying AWS RDS database), I consistently started getting

> MySQL "Error Code 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version."

I get the same error when I use the same LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE commands with AWS RDS Aurora MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 databases. When I issue the load commands using other applications, I don't get this error, so I think the problem is with MySQL WB 8.0. When I enter the command

```
"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'"
```

the result indicates that the value of the `'local_infile'` variable is `"On"`, so I don't think that I need to set `"local_infile = 1"` in the configuration file.  What do I need to do to again successfully load tables in AWS RDS MySQL and Aurora MySQL databases using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE commands issued from MySQL Workbench 8.0?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72220